# How to validate two groups of controls with 1 button and a validation group?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one group of 3 asp.net textboxes and one group of 2 asp.net listboxes. There is one asp.net button.  The listboxes each have an asp.net required field validator tied to them.  The other 3 textboxes in the first group do not have any validation.  When the button is clicked, it should display a message if either of the listboxes does not have anything selected, however, if one of the textboxes in the first group has some value, then it should not matter if the listboxes have any value(s) selected.  I assigned the ValidationGroup vgFirst to the group of textboxes and the ValidationGroup vgSecond to the two listboxes.  I then assigned the ValidationGroup vgSecond to each RequiredFieldValidator and assigned the button a ValidatonGroup of vgSecond.  I think I have everything right, but I am not sure how to handle it with just one button.  Do I have to disable Validation for the listboxes if the text in the textboxes change?  Is this my only option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unforuntately, the RequiredFieldValidator isn't smart enough to be used that way.  I suggest you use a CustomFieldValidator and write your own JavaScript validation or make use of a server-side validation scheme (which should probably be done anyway as I find it to be a bit more reliable than the client-side stuff that gets automatically generated).

edit---
Yes... you will need to enable/disable validation depending on values in your textboxes if you want to continue to use RequireFieldValidators.