# Validation of two sets of controls

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, validation

- ASP.NET WebForms 4.51
- Having read things like [How to validate two groups of controls with 1 button and a validation group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703026/how-to-validate-two-groups-of-controls-with-1-button-and-a-validation-group)

I have a form with the following logical inputs:

1. Name (TextBox)
2. Last Name (TextBox)
3. Profession (Drop Down List)

Profession has the following items:

Bus Driver
Taxi Driver
Not Applicable

Now based on the profession I display a number of other text fields. I have required field validators on all the fields 1..3 as well as the fields for the profession (4..8).

I have a single submit button which triggers the validation. So my question is what is the easiest way to validate controls: 1..3 should the selection be Not Applicable for profession and 1..8 for the other professions from a single button.

I can think of a couple of ways but they are all "messy" and I was looking for a better approach:

1) Have two required field validators per field - one when validating for Not Applicable and one for when a profession is selected. Toggle the validation group when the profession is selected for the button.

I tried this but it does not seem to work as I still get **both** validators firing per field.

2) Write custom client side validators that take into account what is selected in the drop down for profession.

A maintenance nightmare. I would prefer to use any built in functionality MS provides.

So has anyone got any suggestions on how to validate the same sets of controls differently based on what has been selected in another control?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple javascript validation script. You can not validate the javascript on serverside using "page.Isvalid".

Your only option is to write a custom validator. I just don't know why that should be a maintenance nightmare. If you're using the javascript validation you should validate the values in the code behind anyway. Otherwise the user could just disable javascript and enter anything he wants.

Hope it helps...

Comment: There is server side validation in addition to the client side validation. Client side validation is there to avoid the round trip to the server.

Comment: The pain from my perspective is that currently if I use a built in validator I don't have to write any JS as it is generated. If I go and write some custom JS then should controls change on the page I need to then go and refactor (add/remove/rename a control) which is what I am attempting to avoid.